# Use dd to write data starting from a specific location

Tags: linux

I want to use dd to write data starting from a specific location (basically skip the first 50000 bytes ) on a disk and start writing after the first 50000 bytes.  I tried doing this

```
dd of=/dev/disk1 if=/dev/random seek=50000
```

I let the above line run for few mins and then when I cancel it out, I get this

```
0+6 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 79.2458 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Looks to me nothing got copied. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 14):

From [dd docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html):

```
‘seek=n’

Skip n ‘obs’-byte blocks in the output file before copying. 
if ‘oflag=seek_bytes’ is specified, n is interpreted as a byte 
count rather than a block count.
```

So it looks like you want this:

```
dd of=/dev/disk1 if=/dev/random obs=50000  seek=1
```

Or this:

```
dd of=/dev/disk1 if=/dev/random oflag=seek_bytes  seek=50000
```

Another thing is that `/dev/random` will block if kernel pool is empty. You can try `/dev/urandom` instead, which will use other methods to generate a number without blocking when the pool is empty:

```
dd of=/dev/disk1 if=/dev/urandom oflag=seek_bytes  seek=50000
```

Comment: When I use the first command and run it for few secs, i see this        dd of=/dev/disk1 if=/dev/random obs=50000  seek=1
0+8 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 100.714 s, 0.0 kB/s                              Why does it say 0 B copied ?

Comment: Seems at last versions of dd, you should add "B' suffix to seek to count bytes, not blocks. Llike this:
dd of=/dev/disk1 if=/dev/urandom seek=50000B